# Can someone tell me what is the sql expression for below? Result returns true as CD in table A exists partially in value of table B

Tags: sql

Can someone tell me what is the sql expression for below? Result returns true because CD in table A exists partially in value of table B.

Table A:
CD

Table B:
ABCD,CD,ABEF

("ABCD,CD,ABEF" is 1 value in the field of table B)

Comment: This question in manifestly incomplete

Answer (score 0):

```
where 
   TableB.YourField LIKE '%CD%'
```

OR

```
where
   TableB.YourField LIKE '%' + TableA.TheCDField + '%'
```

However, VERY poor design of table content when multiple values concatenated in a single field. Should be normalized, but not enough information provided

Answer (score 0):

Assume TableA has Column1 which contains 'CD' and TableB has Column1 which contains 'ABCD,CD,ABEF'. Your text match is in the middle, but can happen at beginning of string, mid string or at the end of the string. So:

```
select *
from TableA cross join TableB
where
   TableB.Column1 like TableA.Column1 +',%' or
   TableB.Column1 like '%,'+ TableA.Column1 +',%' or
   TableB.Column1 like '%,'+ TableA.Column1
```